# MATLAB finding local maximum in certain range

Tags: matlab, max

[image: Time Domain Signal]

Figure above is my time domain signal and the area enclosed in black is my area of interest.

What I want to do is following:

1. Identify the global minimum point
2. Find a local maximum point that comes before the global minimum point

I have succesfully identified a global minimum point like this:

```
    for ii=1:Size(1)
        for jj=1:Size(2)
            [min_amp, min_index]=min(signal(ii,jj,:));
            min_time(ii,jj)=time(min_index);
        end
    end

    Minbound = floor(mean(min_time(:))*Fs);
```

Size(1) and Size(2) represent the scan area and I tried to find the time at which global minimum occurs at each point and took an average.

Can anyone help me with

**2.** **Find a local maximum point that comes before the global minimum point?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear how your variable signal (3D) is orientated.
I will assume that the third dimension is time, otherwise the search for minimum would not make any sense.

Once you identified the minimum

```
[min_amp, min_index]=min(signal(ii,jj,:));
```

you have the index (min_index) where it is located, and now you have to restrict your search for the maximum until this point (as it has to be before that).

```
[max_amp, max_index]=max(signal(ii,jj,start_index:min_index));
```

As mentioned before, I am not aware of the dimensions of your signal, whether it is the epoch in the black-framed area or your entire time series. Depending on that start_index can be either 1 or the start index of the black-framed epoch.

You should consider to check whether the maximum is a real peak or just the biggest value at the beginning of your interval.

Have a look at the build-in function

```
findpeaks
```

it searches for local maxima. To find the minima you could invert the signal. And restrict the maxima search again only on the interval before the minimum.

Comment: Yes, my time signal has the dimension of 450x450x200 where 200 is my time frame and 450x450 represents scan area

Comment: Glad I could help